# Override core checkout cart controller

Tags: overrides, controllers

I have already included a custom controller in my local module.

The config.xml snippet for it is:

```
       <routers>
          <subscription>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>Born_Subscription</module>
                 <frontName>bornsubscription</frontName>
             </args>         
        </subscription>
       </routers>
```

Now I want to override Mage/Checkout/CartController as well in the same module.

How do I modify my config.xml file to include the override as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add this inside the `<routers>` tag in your config.xml (as a sibling tag for `subscription`)

```
 <checkout>
     <args>
         <modules>
             <Born_Subscription before="Mage_Checkout">Born_Subscription</Born_Subscription>
         </modules>
     </args>
 </checkout>
```

Then create the file `Born/Subscription/controllers/CartController.php` with this content

```
<?php 
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class Born_Subscription_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    //your magic code here
}
```

Comment: if i want to change in deleteAction than i can copy that action and paste in my file and add code in there ri8?

Comment: @Newbie. Yes, you can do that.

Comment: @Matius this one process right i have issue arrived on magento 1.9.2.4 (this one work but why issue arrived)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578195/magento-cart-not-updating-quantity-in-arabic-store-view

Answer (score 0):

app/etc/modules/Overcart_Checkout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Overcart_Checkout>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Overcart_Checkout>
  </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Overcart/Checkout/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Overcart_Checkout>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </Overcart_Checkout>
  </modules>

  <frontend>
    <routers>
       <checkout>
     <args>
         <modules>
             <Overcart_Checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Overcart_Checkout</Overcart_Checkout>
         </modules>
     </args>
 </checkout>
    </routers>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Overcart/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php

```
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class Overcart_Checkout_CartController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

  /**
     * Action list where need check enabled cookie
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_cookieCheckActions = array('add');

    /**
     * Retrieve shopping cart model object
     *
     * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Cart
     */
    protected function _getCart()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
    }

    /**
     * Get checkout session model instance
     *
     * @return Mage_Checkout_Model_Session
     */
    protected function _getSession()
    {
        return Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session');
    }

    /**
     * Get current active quote instance
     *
     * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
     */
    protected function _getQuote()
    {
        return $this->_getCart()->getQuote();
    }

    /**
     * Set back redirect url to response
     *
     * @return Mage_Checkout_CartController
     */
    protected function _goBack()
    {

        $returnUrl = $this->getRequest()->getParam('return_url');
        if ($returnUrl) {

            if (!$this->_isUrlInternal($returnUrl)) {
                throw new Mage_Exception('External urls redirect to "' . $returnUrl . '" denied!');
            }

            $this->_getSession()->getMessages(true);
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($returnUrl);
        } elseif (!Mage::getStoreConfig('checkout/cart/redirect_to_cart')
            && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('in_cart')
            && $backUrl = $this->_getRefererUrl()
        ) {
            $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($backUrl);
        } else {
            if (($this->getRequest()->getActionName() == 'add') && !$this->getRequest()->getParam('in_cart')) {
                $this->_getSession()->setContinueShoppingUrl($this->_getRefererUrl());
            }
            $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage');
        }
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Initialize product instance from request data
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product || false
     */
    protected function _initProduct()
    {
        $productId = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('product');
        if ($productId) {
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->load($productId);
            if ($product->getId()) {
                return $product;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Shopping cart display action
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $cart = $this->_getCart();
        if ($cart->getQuote()->getItemsCount()) {
            $cart->init();
            $cart->save();

            if (!$this->_getQuote()->validateMinimumAmount()) {
                $minimumAmount = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency(Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode())
                    ->toCurrency(Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/amount'));

                $warning = Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/description')
                    ? Mage::getStoreConfig('sales/minimum_order/description')
                    : Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Minimum order amount is %s', $minimumAmount);

                $cart->getCheckoutSession()->addNotice($warning);
            }
        }

        // Compose array of messages to add
        $messages = array();
        foreach ($cart->getQuote()->getMessages() as $message) {
            if ($message) {
                // Escape HTML entities in quote message to prevent XSS
                $message->setCode(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($message->getCode()));
                $messages[] = $message;
            }
        }
        $cart->getCheckoutSession()->addUniqueMessages($messages);

        /**
         * if customer enteres shopping cart we should mark quote
         * as modified bc he can has checkout page in another window.
         */
        $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        $this->_redirect('checkout/onepage');
        Varien_Profiler::start(__METHOD__ . 'cart_display');
        $this
            ->loadLayout()
            ->_initLayoutMessages('checkout/session')
            ->_initLayoutMessages('catalog/session')
            ->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->setTitle($this->__('Shopping Cart'));
        $this->renderLayout();
        Varien_Profiler::stop(__METHOD__ . 'cart_display');
    }

    /**
     * Add product to shopping cart action
     */
    public function addAction()
    {
        $cart   = $this->_getCart();
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $product = $this->_initProduct();
            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');

            /**
             * Check product availability
             */
            if (!$product) {
                $this->_goBack();
                return;
            }

            $cart->addProduct($product, $params);
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }

            $cart->save();

            $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

            /**
             * @todo remove wishlist observer processAddToCart
             */
            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_add_product_complete',
                array('product' => $product, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
            );

            if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()){
                    $message = $this->__('%s was added to your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($product->getName()));
                    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
                }
                $this->_goBack();
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->_getSession()->addNotice(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($message));
                }
            }

            $url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
            if ($url) {
                $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            } else {
                $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_goBack();
        }
    }

    public function addgroupAction()
    {
        $orderItemIds = $this->getRequest()->getParam('order_items', array());
        if (is_array($orderItemIds)) {
            $itemsCollection = Mage::getModel('sales/order_item')
                ->getCollection()
                ->addIdFilter($orderItemIds)
                ->load();
            /* @var $itemsCollection Mage_Sales_Model_Mysql4_Order_Item_Collection */
            $cart = $this->_getCart();
            foreach ($itemsCollection as $item) {
                try {
                    $cart->addOrderItem($item, 1);
                } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
                        $this->_getSession()->addNotice($e->getMessage());
                    } else {
                        $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
                    }
                } catch (Exception $e) {
                    $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot add the item to shopping cart.'));
                    Mage::logException($e);
                    $this->_goBack();
                }
            }
            $cart->save();
            $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        }
        $this->_goBack();
    }

    /**
     * Action to reconfigure cart item
     */
    public function configureAction()
    {
        // Extract item and product to configure
        $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $quoteItem = null;
        $cart = $this->_getCart();
        if ($id) {
            $quoteItem = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($id);
        }

        if (!$quoteItem) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Quote item is not found.'));
            $this->_redirect('checkout/cart');
            return;
        }

        try {
            $params = new Varien_Object();
            $params->setCategoryId(false);
            $params->setConfigureMode(true);
            $params->setBuyRequest($quoteItem->getBuyRequest());

            Mage::helper('catalog/product_view')->prepareAndRender($quoteItem->getProduct()->getId(), $this, $params);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot configure product.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Update product configuration for a cart item
     */
    public function updateItemOptionsAction()
    {
        $cart   = $this->_getCart();
        $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

        if (!isset($params['options'])) {
            $params['options'] = array();
        }
        try {
            if (isset($params['qty'])) {
                $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                );
                $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            }

            $quoteItem = $cart->getQuote()->getItemById($id);
            if (!$quoteItem) {
                Mage::throwException($this->__('Quote item is not found.'));
            }

            $item = $cart->updateItem($id, new Varien_Object($params));
            if (is_string($item)) {
                Mage::throwException($item);
            }
            if ($item->getHasError()) {
                Mage::throwException($item->getMessage());
            }

            $related = $this->getRequest()->getParam('related_product');
            if (!empty($related)) {
                $cart->addProductsByIds(explode(',', $related));
            }

            $cart->save();

            $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);

            Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_item_complete',
                array('item' => $item, 'request' => $this->getRequest(), 'response' => $this->getResponse())
            );
            if (!$this->_getSession()->getNoCartRedirect(true)) {
                if (!$cart->getQuote()->getHasError()){
                    $message = $this->__('%s was updated in your shopping cart.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($item->getProduct()->getName()));
                    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($message);
                }
                $this->_goBack();
            }
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            if ($this->_getSession()->getUseNotice(true)) {
                $this->_getSession()->addNotice($e->getMessage());
            } else {
                $messages = array_unique(explode("\n", $e->getMessage()));
                foreach ($messages as $message) {
                    $this->_getSession()->addError($message);
                }
            }

            $url = $this->_getSession()->getRedirectUrl(true);
            if ($url) {
                $this->getResponse()->setRedirect($url);
            } else {
                $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::helper('checkout/cart')->getCartUrl());
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot update the item.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
            $this->_goBack();
        }
        $this->_redirect('*/*');
    }

    /**
     * Update shopping cart data action
     */
    public function updatePostAction()
    {
        $updateAction = (string)$this->getRequest()->getParam('update_cart_action');

        switch ($updateAction) {
            case 'empty_cart':
                $this->_emptyShoppingCart();
                break;
            case 'update_qty':
                $this->_updateShoppingCart();
                break;
            default:
                $this->_updateShoppingCart();
        }

        $this->_goBack();
    }

    /**
     * Update customer's shopping cart
     */
    protected function _updateShoppingCart()
    {
        try {
            $cartData = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cart');
            if (is_array($cartData)) {
                $filter = new Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    array('locale' => Mage::app()->getLocale()->getLocaleCode())
                );
                foreach ($cartData as $index => $data) {
                    if (isset($data['qty'])) {
                        $cartData[$index]['qty'] = $filter->filter(trim($data['qty']));
                    }
                }
                $cart = $this->_getCart();
                if (! $cart->getCustomerSession()->getCustomer()->getId() && $cart->getQuote()->getCustomerId()) {
                    $cart->getQuote()->setCustomerId(null);
                }

                $cartData = $cart->suggestItemsQty($cartData);
                $cart->updateItems($cartData)
                    ->save();
            }
            $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError(Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($e->getMessage()));
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($e, $this->__('Cannot update shopping cart.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Empty customer's shopping cart
     */
    protected function _emptyShoppingCart()
    {
        try {
            $this->_getCart()->truncate()->save();
            $this->_getSession()->setCartWasUpdated(true);
        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $exception) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($exception->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $this->_getSession()->addException($exception, $this->__('Cannot update shopping cart.'));
        }
    }

    /**
     * Delete shoping cart item action
     */
    public function deleteAction()
    {
        $id = (int) $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        if ($id) {
            try {
                $this->_getCart()->removeItem($id)
                  ->save();
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot remove the item.'));
                Mage::logException($e);
            }
        }
        $this->_redirectReferer(Mage::getUrl('*/*'));
    }

    /**
     * Initialize shipping information
     */
    public function estimatePostAction()
    {
        $country    = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('country_id');
        $postcode   = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_postcode');
        $city       = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_city');
        $regionId   = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('region_id');
        $region     = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('region');

        $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()
            ->setCountryId($country)
            ->setCity($city)
            ->setPostcode($postcode)
            ->setRegionId($regionId)
            ->setRegion($region)
            ->setCollectShippingRates(true);
        $this->_getQuote()->save();
        $this->_goBack();
    }

    public function estimateUpdatePostAction()
    {
        $code = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('estimate_method');
        if (!empty($code)) {
            $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod($code)/*->collectTotals()*/->save();
        }
        $this->_goBack();
    }

    /**
     * Initialize coupon
     */
    public function couponPostAction()
    {
        /**
         * No reason continue with empty shopping cart
         */
        if (!$this->_getCart()->getQuote()->getItemsCount()) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }

        $couponCode = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');
        if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('remove') == 1) {
            $couponCode = '';
        }
        $oldCouponCode = $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode();

        if (!strlen($couponCode) && !strlen($oldCouponCode)) {
            $this->_goBack();
            return;
        }

        try {
            $this->_getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);
            $this->_getQuote()->setCouponCode(strlen($couponCode) ? $couponCode : '')
                ->collectTotals()
                ->save();

            if (strlen($couponCode)) {
                if ($couponCode == $this->_getQuote()->getCouponCode()) {
                    $this->_getSession()->addSuccess(
                        $this->__('Coupon code "%s" was applied.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($couponCode))
                    );
                }
                else {
                    $this->_getSession()->addError(
                        $this->__('Coupon code "%s" is not valid.', Mage::helper('core')->htmlEscape($couponCode))
                    );
                }
            } else {
                $this->_getSession()->addSuccess($this->__('Coupon code was canceled.'));
            }

        } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('Cannot apply the coupon code.'));
            Mage::logException($e);
        }

        $this->_goBack();
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Magento SE and thanks for your contribution. Unfortunately such a huge amount of code without any explanation is not very helpful. Please explain at least briefly what it does and why. By the way, it looks like you copied the complete core controller which is not necessary if you only want to override a single method.