# Overriding Magento CartController not working

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, overrides, magento-core

I am trying to override Magento Core **CartController**, But the core **CartController** is loading 
**config.xml** (inside `community/Company/BnOverride/etc/`)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_BnOverride>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Company_BnOverride>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
          <checkout>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <company_bnoverride before="Mage_Checkout">Company_BnOverride</company_bnoverride>
                    </modules>
                </args>
           </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

**CartController.php** inside (`community/Company/BnOverride/controllers/`)

```
<?php 
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/CartController.php';
class Company_BnOverride_CartController extends Mage_Checkout_CartController
{
    /**
     * Shopping cart display action
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {

        echo "Cart page";
        exit;
 }
```

And **Company_BnOverride.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_BnOverride>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Company_BnOverride>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace Code in `Config.xml` file with :

```
<checkout>
     <args>
         <modules>
             <Company_Bnoverride before="Mage_Checkout">Company_BnOverride</Company_Bnoverride>
         </modules>
     </args>
 </checkout>
```

Also Replace `Company_BnOverride.xml` File

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Company_BnOverride>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
        </Company_BnOverride>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made the changes but still not loading the extended controller

Comment: Go for the Edited Answer

Comment: Edited : `config.xml` file go for that.

Comment: @user2638108:you can also upvote my answer

Answer (score 2):

change

```
<company_bnoverride before="Mage_Checkout_Cart">Company_BnOverride</company_bnoverride>
```

to

```
<company_bnoverride before="Mage_Checkout">Company_BnOverride</company_bnoverride>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made the changes but still not loading the extended controller

Comment: @user2638108 try with `<Company_BnOverride before="Mage_Checkout">Company_BnOverride</Company_BnOverride>` also check example http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71598/override-core-checkout-cart-controller

Answer (score 0):

Replace your controller frontend xml code with below one,

```
 <frontend>
       <routers>
           <checkout>
                 <args>
                     <modules>
                         <company_bnoverride before="Mage_Checkout">Company_BnOverride</company_bnoverride>
                      </modules>
                 </args>
           </checkout>
       </routers>
 </frontend>
```

You have to keep only **Mage_Checkout** instead of **Mage_Checkout_Cart**

Just keep Module name declaration of override module. Here in your case is checkout module.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I made the changes but still not loading the extended controller

Comment: <mage_checkout before="Mage_Checkout">Company_BnOverride</mage_checkout> try with this

Comment: You can close this question after accept any one answer. Thanks.