# getUrl not finding public function in Controller

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, coupon

I am adding a coupon code block on the final step of One Page checkout, the review step.

I have added a public function couponAction in the

```
app/local/COMPANY/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php

public function couponAction() {

    $this->loadLayout('checkout_onepage_review');

    $this->couponCode = (string) $this->getRequest()->getParam('coupon_code');
    $codeLength = strlen($this->couponCode );

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->setCollectShippingRates(true);

    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->setCouponCode(strlen($this->couponCode) ?

        $this->couponCode : ' ')->collectTotals()->save();

    if ($codeLength) {
        if ( $this->couponCode == Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getCouponCode()) {
            $result['success']='true';
            $result['error'] = false;
            $result['message']=$this->__('Coupon code "%s" was applied.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($this->couponCode));
        } else {
            $result['success']='false';
            // $result['error']=true;
            $result['error_message']=$this->__('Coupon code "%s" is not valid.', Mage::helper('core')->escapeHtml($this->couponCode));

        }
    } else {

        $result['success']='true';
        $result['error']=false;
        $result['message']=$this->__('Coupon code was canceled.');

    }

    $result['goto_section'] = 'review';

    $result['update_section'] = array( 'name' => 'review', 'html' => $this->_getReviewHtml() );

    $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($result));

}
```

it is called from

```
app/design/COMPANY/COMPANY/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml
```

with this

```
<form id="discount-coupon-form" action="<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/coupon', array('_secure'=>true)) ?>" method="post">
```

I have the JS code in

```
app/design/COMPANY/COMPANY/template/checkout/onepage.phtml

<script>
//<![CDATA[
function updateCoupon(reqid) {
    var reqid;
    if(reqid == 2) { $('coupon_code').setValue(''); }
    $('discount-coupon-form').request({
        method: 'post',
        onComplete: payment.onComplete,
        onSuccess: payment.onSave,
        onFailure: checkout.ajaxFailure.bind(checkout)
     })
}
//]]>
```

app/code/local/Checkout/etc/config.xml

```
 <config>
<modules>
    <Mage_Checkout>
        <version>1.6.0.0</version>
    </Mage_Checkout>
</modules>
<global>
    <fieldsets>
        <customer_account>
            <prefix>
                <to_order>customer_prefix</to_order>
            </prefix>
            <firstname>
                <to_order>customer_firstname</to_order>
            </firstname>
            <middlename>
                <to_order>customer_middlename</to_order>
            </middlename>
            <lastname>
                <to_order>customer_lastname</to_order>
            </lastname>
            <suffix>
                <to_order>customer_suffix</to_order>
            </suffix>
            <email>
                <to_order>customer_email</to_order>
            </email>
            <group_id>
                <to_order>customer_group_id</to_order>
            </group_id>
            <tax_class_id>
                <to_order>customer_tax_class_id</to_order>
            </tax_class_id>
        </customer_account>
        <checkout_onepage_billing>
            <prefix>
                <to_customer>*</to_customer>
            </prefix>
            <firstname>
                <to_customer>*</to_customer>
            </firstname>
            <middlename>
                <to_customer>*</to_customer>
            </middlename>
            <lastname>
                <to_customer>*</to_customer>
            </lastname>
            <suffix>
                <to_customer>*</to_customer>
            </suffix>
            <email>
                <to_customer>*</to_customer>
            </email>
            <customer_dob>
                <to_customer>dob</to_customer>
            </customer_dob>
            <customer_taxvat>
                <to_customer>taxvat</to_customer>
            </customer_taxvat>
            <customer_gender>
                <to_customer>gender</to_customer>
            </customer_gender>
        </checkout_onepage_billing>
        <checkout_onepage_quote>
            <customer_prefix>
                <to_customer>prefix</to_customer>
            </customer_prefix>
            <customer_firstname>
                <to_customer>firstname</to_customer>
            </customer_firstname>
            <customer_middlename>
                <to_customer>middlename</to_customer>
            </customer_middlename>
            <customer_lastname>
                <to_customer>lastname</to_customer>
            </customer_lastname>
            <customer_suffix>
                <to_customer>suffix</to_customer>
            </customer_suffix>
            <customer_email>
                <to_customer>email</to_customer>
            </customer_email>
            <customer_dob>
                <to_customer>dob</to_customer>
            </customer_dob>
            <customer_taxvat>
                <to_customer>taxvat</to_customer>
            </customer_taxvat>
            <customer_gender>
                <to_customer>gender</to_customer>
            </customer_gender>
        </checkout_onepage_quote>
    </fieldsets>
    <blocks>
        <checkout>
            <class>Mage_Checkout_Block</class>
        </checkout>
    </blocks>
    <models>
        <checkout>
            <class>Mage_Checkout_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>checkout_resource</resourceModel>
        </checkout>
        <checkout_resource>
            <class>Mage_Checkout_Model_Resource</class>
            <deprecatedNode>checkout_mysql4</deprecatedNode>
            <entities>
                <agreement>
                    <table>checkout_agreement</table>
                </agreement>
                <agreement_store>
                    <table>checkout_agreement_store</table>
                </agreement_store>
            </entities>
        </checkout_resource>
    </models>
    <resources>
        <checkout_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Mage_Checkout</module>
                <class>Mage_Checkout_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </checkout_setup>
    </resources>
    <template>
        <email>
            <checkout_payment_failed_template translate="label" module="sales">
                <label>Payment Failed</label>
                <file>payment_failed.html</file>
                <type>html</type>
            </checkout_payment_failed_template>
        </email>
    </template>
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <totals>
                <nominal>
                    <renderer>checkout/total_nominal</renderer>
                </nominal>
            </totals>
        </quote>
    </sales>
</global>
<frontend>
    <secure_url>
        <checkout_onepage>/checkout/onepage</checkout_onepage>
        <checkout_multishipping>/checkout/multishipping</checkout_multishipping>
    </secure_url>
    <events>
        <customer_login>
            <observers>
                <loadCustomerQuote>
                    <class>checkout/observer</class>
                    <method>loadCustomerQuote</method>
                </loadCustomerQuote>
            </observers>
        </customer_login>
        <customer_logout>
            <observers>
                <unsetAll>
                    <class>checkout/observer</class>
                    <method>unsetAll</method>
                </unsetAll>
            </observers>
        </customer_logout>
        <sales_quote_save_after>
            <observers>
                <set_checkout_quote_id>
                    <class>checkout/observer</class>
                    <method>salesQuoteSaveAfter</method>
                </set_checkout_quote_id>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_save_after>
    </events>
    <routers>
        <checkout>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Mage_Checkout</module>
                <frontName>checkout</frontName>
            </args>
        </checkout>
    </routers>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Mage_Checkout>
                <files>
                    <default>Mage_Checkout.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Mage_Checkout>
        </modules>
    </translate>
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <checkout>
                <file>checkout.xml</file>
            </checkout>
        </updates>
    </layout>
</frontend>
<adminhtml>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Mage_Checkout>
                <files>
                    <default>Mage_Checkout.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Mage_Checkout>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</adminhtml>
<default>
    <checkout>
        <options>
            <onepage_checkout_enabled>1</onepage_checkout_enabled>
            <guest_checkout>1</guest_checkout>
        </options>
        <cart>
            <delete_quote_after>30</delete_quote_after>
            <redirect_to_cart>1</redirect_to_cart>
            <grouped_product_image>itself</grouped_product_image>
            <configurable_product_image>parent</configurable_product_image>
        </cart>
        <cart_link>
            <use_qty>1</use_qty>
        </cart_link>
        <sidebar>
            <display>1</display>
            <count>3</count>
        </sidebar>
        <payment_failed>
            <identity>general</identity>
            <reciever>general</reciever>
            <template>checkout_payment_failed_template</template>
        </payment_failed>
    </checkout>
</default>
```

yet I am always getting 
404 url not found after inputing a valid coupon code on final review page.

Am I missing something in the API.xml file? I am at a loss. Thanks! for any help

Comment: API.xml file? means?

Comment: app/code/local/Checkout/etc/api.xml
Not sure if I have to add anything in that file or some other file

Comment: Post the content of `app/local/COMPANY/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php`

Comment: Added code above

Comment: @John can you please also add your config.xml?

Comment: sorry for delay thanks for help. Config is posted @sv3n

Comment: You did not add any code to override controller file to your `config.xml` refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/71599/23825

Comment: @John worng config.xml :) Please post the one from YOUR/MODULE/etc/config.xml.

Comment: @sv3n Woops! ... I updated it. Thanks for taking the time to look

Comment: @John this was confix.xml from `Mage_Checkout` ... there has to be an config.xml in your created extension folder.

Comment: Thats the thing,  I am just adding all this code into the Checkout.  I was hoping to avoid making a whole new extension @sv3n

Answer (score 0):

Please check onepage controller is rewritten properly or not. Please Check http://yourhost.com/checkout/onepage/coupon is working properly or getting 404.